# jQuery and Json push issue

Tags: json

I am okay with using push({}) to create my javascript array, however one of my fields has a list of its own. So I'm having trouble doing the push() on level down.

As follows, tradeDetails array is defined and the EXTENSIONS field has a collection of values. How do I handle this one below.

```
function TradeDetailsToJson(xml) {    

var tradeDetails = [];
var tradeId = $(xml).find("tradeHeader tradeId").text();
var tradeDate = $(xml).find("tradeHeader tradeDate").text();
var tradeType = $(xml).find("tradeHeader tradeType").text();
var counterparty = $(xml).find("tradeHeader counterparty").text();
var internalUnit = $(xml).find("tradeHeader internalUnit").text();
var buySell = $(xml).find("tradeHeader buySell").text();
var status = $(xml).find("tradeHeader status").text();
tradeDetails.push({
    "tradeId": tradeId,
    "tradeDate": tradeDate,
    "tradeType": tradeType,
    "counterparty": counterparty,
    "internalUnit": internalUnit,
    "buySell": buySell,
    "status": status,
    "**extensions**":[]
});

// NOW I'D LIKE TO PUSH MY EXTENSIONS !!
var extName = ""
var extValue = "";
$(xml).find("extensions extension").each(function () {
    extName = $(this).find("name").text();
    extValue = $(this).find("value").text();
    //tradeDetails[extensions].push({ "name": name, "value": value }); ??????
});
}
```

thank you in advanced.
Bob

Answer (score 1):

Use push on the `extensions` property again?

```
tradeDetails.push({
    "tradeId": tradeId,
    "tradeDate": tradeDate,
    "tradeType": tradeType,
    "counterparty": counterparty,
    "internalUnit": internalUnit,
    "buySell": buySell,
    "status": status,
    "extensions":[]
});

tradeDetails.extensions.push({ "name": name, "value": value });
```

With what you have tried, you need to wrap `extensions` which is the key of the object `tradeDetails`, in quotes.

So change

```
tradeDetails[extensions].push({ "name": name, "value": value });
```

to

```
tradeDetails["extensions"].push({ "name": name, "value": value });
```

Comment: we were both close ! This worked:     tradeDetails[0].extensions.push({ "name": extName, "value": extValue });